# How to call a feature file inside a for loop in karate?

Tags: karate

Lets say my variable is like

```
queryParam = [{"coupon_id": 1,"code": "test"},{"coupon_id": 1,"code": "test"}]
```

Now lets say I want to call one feature file with

```
param= {"coupon_id": 1,"code": "test"}
```

and again with param
    param= {"coupon_id": 1,"code": "test"}

Actually I am calling one api with multiple parameters.

Comment: Ok @peter also I got my answer  https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/callarray/call-json-array.feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this example: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/callarray/call-json-array.feature

Here since [`kittens.json`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/callarray/kittens.json) is an array, the `call` will loop.

```
* def creator = read('kitten-create.feature')
* def kittens = read('kittens.json')
* def result = call creator kittens
```